# Wix Bootstrapper how to uninstall packages in different order from the install order

Tags: wix, burn

My wix bootstrapper has a chain that looks like this:

```
<Chain>
    <MsiPackage Id="msipack"/>
    <ExePackage Id="exepack"/>
</Chain>
```

`msipack` installs all program files on the computer as well as some files necessary for `exepack` to run. However when uninstalling the bootstrapper I want to run `exepack` first because if it is run after `msipack`, then the files needed for the uninstall of `exepack` are already removed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the bootstrapper already did what I wanted it to. It just didn't wait for the uninstall of `exepack` to finish so it deleted the files and the uninstall failed.

Comment: As you saw, the chain is automatically reversed for uninstall (and rollback). It's not true that it doesn't wait for the `ExePackage` to finish. If you are seeing this, then you must have an .exe that kicks off a process and then exits. Hopefully there is a command line switch you can add to your .exe to make it wait on the real process before exiting.